# PostgreSQL. How to insert values from another insert?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables and need select records from 1-st then insert records to 2-nd and finally insert records to 3-rd

```
CREATE TABLE public.t_sender (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_sender_id_seq'::regclass),
  soft_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  sender_model_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE public.t_receiver (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_receiver_id_seq'::regclass),
  receiver_owner_id BIGINT,
  );

CREATE TABLE public.t_sender_to_receiver (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_sender_to_receiver_id_seq'::regclass),
  sender_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  receiver_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (sender_id) REFERENCES public.t_sender (id)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (receiver_id) REFERENCES public.t_receiver (id)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

I get a ID values from 1st table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectreceiverWithoutsender(user_id_param bigint) 
    RETURNS setof bigint AS $BODY$
    SELECT id FROM t_receiver WHERE id in (SELECT receiver_id FROM t_user_to_receiver WHERE user_id_param=$1) AND id NOT IN (SELECT receiver_id FROM t_sender_to_receiver);
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then do insert to 2-nd and 3-rd tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertSendersForUserId(user_id_param bigint)
    RETURNS void AS $BODY$
BEGIN
        WITH insSender AS (insert into t_sender(sender_status, soft_id) select 1,0  from selectReceiverWithoutSender($1) RETURNING id)
        INSERT INTO t_sender_to_receiver(receiver_id, sender_id) VALUES ((selectReceiverWithoutSender($1)), (select id from insSender) );
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My issue is that I get multiple ID values from 1st insert **insSender** and get the next error when I tried to execute fuction:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    select 1 from insertDadsForUserId(44);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000 
>   Context: SQL statement "WITH insSender AS (insert into t_sender...

So how can I prepare this values for inserting to next insert?

I'm sorry if it is not very difficult question, I have experienced PostgresSQL function at first time and haven't fount the solution in internet.

Comment: I was recommended to use a bit different approach 
1) calculate value of sequence     
idSender := nextval('t_sender_id_seq'::regclass);
2) execute both insert in loop by one record. 
I'll publish code soon.